# string[index] not working as I would assume

Tags: c#, string

I have this code which gets the index of the '[' in the string. It then creates an integer from the next character in the string which I would assume would be '9' in this example. However `value` is getting set to 57?

```
string text = "Red Onyx : Text 1 - [9]";

int index = text.IndexOf("[");
int value = Convert.ToInt16(text[index+1]);
```

I have tried doing just text[index], text[index -1], and text[index +2]

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/  57 (integer) is the ascii value of "9".  "9" is a numeral not an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text[index+1]` would return you a character and converting it to `Int16` will return its ASCII value which is `57` for `9`.

You can use [`char.GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
int value = (int) char.GetNumericValue(text[index + 1]);
```

or use the second overload of [`char.GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdb0at4t(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes string and index like:

```
int value = (int) char.GetNumericValue(text,index + 1);
```

Or

```
int value = Convert.ToInt16(text[index + 1] +""); //explicitly make it string "9"
                                                  //or simpler text[index + 1].ToString()
```

Also there is no need to use `Convert.ToInt16` if you are going to store result in `Int32` or `int`

Comment: +1. I was just typing this. You're faster than me. You could also do `Convert.ToInt16(text.SubString(index+1,1))` or `Convert.ToInt16(text[index+1].ToString())`